# remove all special characters and numbers using python

Tags: python

I have a list like below:

```
issue=[[hi iam !@going $%^ to uk&*(us \\r\\ntomorrow {morning} by the_way 
        two-three!~`` [problems]:are there;]
      [happy"journey" and \\r\\n\\rbring 576 chachos?><,.|\/)]]
```

I have tried below code but im not getting desired output:

```
import re
ab=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', issue)
bc=re.split(r's, ab)
```

I would like to see output like below:

```
issue_output=[['hi' 'iam' 'going' 'to' 'uk' 'us' 'tomorrow' 'morning' 'by' 
                'the' 'way' 'two' 'three' 'problems' 'are' 'there']
              [ 'happy' 'journey' 'and' 'bring' 'chachos']]
```

Comment: I don't think that you are going to be able to do that with a Regular Expression since you want to replace punctuation with a space in some cases, and with nothing in others.

Comment: could you properly format your issue? is it all string, or array of strings? or array of array of strings?

Comment: issue is in list format

Comment: The input is not very clearly formatted. Is it a string or a list hierarchy of some kind?

Comment: When I copy/paste your issue I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Could you fix it so it will be easier to help you? Pleas read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Replaces all unwanted characters with whitespace. Then gets rid of multi-whitespace by single whitespace.

```
issue = '[[hi iam !@going $%^ to uk&*(us tomorrow {morning} by the_way two-three!~`` problems:are there;],[happy"journey" and bring 576chachos?><,.|\/)]]'
tmp = "".join(x if x.isalpha() or x.isspace() else " " for x in issue)
result = " ".join(tmp.split())
print(result)
```

If you want the square brackets:

```
tmp = "".join(x if x.isalpha() or x.isspace() or x in ["[", "]"] else " " for x in issue)
```

Answer (score 0):

use re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', issue)